# Why compiler behaves differently with this code?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

In C#, the following method will not compile:

```
public bool IsItTrue()
{
}
```

The compiler errors : 'IsItTrue()': not all code paths return a value, which makes perfect sense. But the following compile without any issue.

```
public bool IsItTrue()
{
    while (true)
    {
    }
}
```

Which looks wrong as no return statement at all.  Why is it so? Any help here...,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The compiler knows that the second method will never return.

If either method ever returns in any circumstances then they must return a `bool`.

The first method doesn't contain any infinite loops, doesn't throw any unconditional exceptions etc, so it must return a `bool`. The code doesn't return a `bool` so the compiler refuses to compile it.

The second method never returns because of the infinite `while (true)` loop. If it *never* returns then it doesn't matter what (if anything) is *never* returned so the compiler will allow it to compile.

A few more examples that the compiler will recognise and allow:

```
public bool IsItTrue()
{
    throw new Exception("Always thrown!");
}

public bool HowAboutThisOne()
{
    if ((46 - 3) < (27 * 9))
    {
        throw new Exception("Always thrown!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that the compiler would allow that.  I can see why it *could* be allowed, but I wonder what real-life purpose that serves.

Comment: I know that we might want something similar to a while(true) for a thread but even a thread should end at some point? So if the compiler can detect such a situation why does it not throw an error point an infinite loop?

Comment: This works because the loop or condition expression can be evaluated at compile time.  See my answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952634/why-compiler-behaves-differently-with-this-code/1953368#1953368

Answer (score 3):

The first is explained nicely by the compiler error message.

The second *never returns*, so there's *never* any value returned.

It's not the same. In your first example the method could return without giving any value back to the caller -> Compiler error.

The second will never return (the compiler is smart enough for that, it figures out that you created an infinite loop). It won't ever enter the "Okay, I reached the end of the method and don't know what to return" state.

Answer (score 1):

The [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) states that you can not generally determine if a program will terminate or run forever.  Given that there are examples in this thread that seem to violate this principle, I suspect that the C# compiler is performing analysis on the loop conditions that can be reduced to a **compile time constant**.  If the constant evaluates to `true`, then we know that the loop will never terminate.

For example, consider the following two functions.

```
public bool NoError()
{
    while (true) { }
}

public bool Error()
{
    while (NoError()) { }
}
```

As demonstrated, the first function will not generate a compile time error.  However, the second will since the compiler can not evaluate the result of the function call `NoError()`.  This is also the case if `NoError()` is modified to always return `true`.